# create the curve with tailwindCss

Tags: css, user-interface, tailwind-css

How could I create the curve like the top blue border with Tailwind CSS classes explicitly not using CSS stylesheet?

[image]

Comment: It is not possible to create this exact curve with tailwind, it is too specific. You can create an svg with some svg drawer, or do it with classic css

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: this is not a tailwindcss related question. you have to use custom classes or arbitrary values.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** After some research, i figured out a way to achieve this.

##### Rounded Border:

```
<div class="overflow-x-hidden">
  <div class="absolute bottom-0 mt-[100px] ml-[-50%] h-[500px] w-[200%] rounded-t-[100%] bg-gradient-to-b from-blue-400 via-blue-500 to-blue-600">
    <div class="mt-5 text-center text-2xl text-white">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

##### Rounded Corners:

Using `rounded` class with attribute value for simple curve at corners.

```
<div class="h-[100px] rounded-t-[100px] bg-blue-500">
  <div class="p-5 text-center text-2xl text-white">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Refer: https://play.tailwindcss.com/fV3c2H8TOu for further changes

Comment: thank for your suggestion ,but I don't want the top border to be horizontal

Comment: Please find the changes in the edit. i have edited the answer according to your requirement .